# In Ruby on Rails, the :id is only optional in routes.rb? How to tell optional vs not optional?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In routes.rb

```
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
  map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

but then

```
http://localhost:3000/foobars/alt
```

will work too.  The params are:

```
{"action"=>"alt", "controller"=>"foobars"}
```

so looks like `:id` is optional here.  How can you tell it is optional vs not optional?  Can you make it so that it is not optional in routes.rb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :requirements to impose some conditions on :id for the route to match, ie: map.connect ':controller/:action/:id', :requirements => { :id => /\d{4}/ } . That way, if :id doesn't match the requirement, the route won't match either.

Answer (score 0):

In the controller, you should just give an error if `params[:id]` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

http://localhost:3000/foobars/alt

To achieve this path you have to  mention this route in routes.rb.

something like following

```
map.resources :foobars, :collection=> {:alt=>:get }
```

otherwise it will treat alt as params[:id] and if you create controller using scaffolding it will go to the `show` action of your `foobars` controller.

```
So for above mention url it becomes optional and treat it as an action insetad of params[:id]
```